# When I try to display two DIVS next to each other, the one on the right is lower than the left

Tags: html, css

I try to display two sections on a website next to each other in line and the one on the right always goes slightly lower than the one on the left. It looks like this:

[image]

```
<div class="container">
<div id="left">Content</div>
<div id="right">Content</div>
</div>

.container{display:inline-block;width:200px}

#left, #right{float:left;width:100px}
```

Comment: you should look into a more modern layout approach that doesn't involve floats - might I suggest flexbox? http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Recommendations are good, but first try to help him understand what's wrong with his CSS.

Comment: I use Bootstrap which usually takes care of the problem. There's an occasional time where I have to edit an old website still using old code and I just want to know how to fix this in those scenarios.

Comment: @JordanForeman I think it's a little early to suggest that floats are not a modern approach.

Comment: I can't replicate your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/uuu7nqqa/ This looks right to me. Any ideas?

Comment: Your actual code has no problem http://jsfiddle.net/67kwfanw/1/ ... Try to replicate your issue

Comment: please post your full HTML, I bet there is some other element on the page which is pushing the right div down may be, the snippet you posted doesnt cause issues,also what browser are you seeing this behavior?

Comment: @hungerstar haha yeah...I suppose you're right. But I do believe its a practice that is slowly making its way out the proverbial door. It can get complicated really quickly, and IMHO is often unnecessary when options like `inline-block` and flexbox solve the same problem without all of the headaches. Floats were not intended for the kinds of layouts that we've adapted them to over the years, and that's why we're seeing things like flexbox becoming more and more popular. Ultimately, it is all a matter of preference, but I'll stick to my suggestion that you should avoid floating if possible.

Comment: my guess is that you have a space, tab or some other character  between the two `DIV`s that is causing this. I replicated your issue in a fiddle by adding a `&nbsp;` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uuu7nqqa/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. 
Adding

```
vertical-align: top;
```

to the columns solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what was happening in your example was that your container div was creating a pseudo-margin for your right div.

You should eventually look into clearing floats:

anyway this is working:

```css
.container > div {
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
display: inline-block;
}

.container:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  clear: both;
 }
.left {
  background-color: blue;
 }
.right {
  background-color: red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">Content</div>
  <div class="right">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is this different form first answer?

Comment: basically similar - I just added pseudo element on container div to clear floats

Answer (score -1):

Your container doesn't need to be `inline-block`, but your divs need to be.

I'd also shy away from ids, so my code doesn't use them, and instead only relies on a simple `.container` class:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div style="background-color: red;"></div>
    <div style="background-color: blue;"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.container > div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle showing this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/ke2dj9oe/

Comment: lets discuss our downvotes please. From my understanding, this solves OPs problem, is a fully-qualified answer (with code **and** a link to an example).

Comment: That's the only plausible reason I could infer as well; however if that is the case, then this entire question should be closed. Is it against the site's meta to suggest alternative approaches that (at least IMO) could benefit OP? If that is the case, I'll accept my downvote. But for anyone seeing this in the future, this is a perfectly acceptable solution for the kind of laying out that OP is trying to achieve. I'm not bitter at all!

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what the final use of the DIVs will be but I do not use `display: inline-block` myself if I am using the to section a website, i.e. content column from sidebar column. The reason? inline-block elements will produce a single space gap between each element which can be undesirable for some designs.

I've pretty much simplified what you have above with the code below.

```css
.left,
.right {
  color: white;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.left {
  background-color: blue;
}
.right {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">Content</div>
  <div class="right">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Danko LOL, yes, I know. It is a little unclear what the OP is asking for. It seems that they do not want the DIVs to be uneven. Thanks for the down vote.

Answer (score -1):

I used your code to create this jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/afxxgwmp/)

Everything works fine for me. Does this solve your problem?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="left">Content</div>
    <div id="right">Content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px; 
    font-family: Helvetica;
    color: #fff;
}

#left,
#right {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height: 200px;
}

#left {
    background: #493ddb;   
}

#right {
     background: #cc373d;
}
```